# FLoated elements top alignment

Tags: css, floating

I need to place every odd element on left, and every even elements on right like the below image.

[image]

Please check the fiddle for what I have done so far. https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/na4fwkg7/

How can I remove the extra space above and below the third green item?

Here is the code

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
li:nth-child(odd){
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
li:nth-child(even){
  border: 2px solid green;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis aliquid eos sint et autem optio? Optio </li>
  <li>culpa, nisi, dolore maiores aut vel cum</li>
  <li> totam non ab voluptatibus assumenda quasi, blanditiis?</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis aliquid eos sint et autem optio? Optio </li>
  <li>culpa, nisi, dolore maiores aut vel cum</li>
  <li> totam non ab voluptatibus assumenda quasi, blanditiis?</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis aliquid eos sint et autem optio? Optio </li>
  <li>culpa, nisi, dolore maiores aut vel cum</li>
  <li> totam non ab voluptatibus assumenda quasi, blanditiis?</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which space you want to remove?

Comment: there is some extra space above and below the third green item, with content "test"

Comment: for this i think best solution to use display: inline-block. you can try that

Comment: tried inline-block with lesser width, but blocks are not moving up to fill the space

Comment: I don't think you can do that without dividing the odds and the evens in 2 columns. I tried everything else. Tried using `display:flex;` and it's other properties. No luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

```
li:nth-child(even){
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Your fiddle with this change - https://jsfiddle.net/e5p15160/

Comment: the floated left items wont move up. Check this case [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/e5p15160/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/e5p15160/1/)

Comment: @Goombah Adding `float` will override `dispaly-inline` property, so previous example will break

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it's suitable for you, I added position as relative in li for css:

```
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis aliquid eos sint et autem optio? Optio </li>
<li>culpa, nisi, dolore maiores aut vel cum</li>
<li> totam non ab voluptatibus assumenda quasi, blanditiis?</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis aliquid eos sint et autem optio? Optio </li>
<li>culpa, nisi, dolore maiores aut vel cum</li>
<li> totam non ab voluptatibus assumenda quasi, blanditiis?</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis aliquid eos sint et autem optio? Optio </li>
<li>culpa, nisi, dolore maiores aut vel cum</li>
<li> totam non ab voluptatibus assumenda quasi, blanditiis?</li>
</ul>
<style>
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
li{
list-style: none;
border: 2px solid red;
margin: 0 0 10px;
width: 50%;
position:relative;
}

li:nth-child(odd){
float: left;
clear: left;
}

li:nth-child(even){
border: 2px solid green;
float: right;
clear: right;
}
</style>
```